# (Blender 2.9) Viewport Cycles render progress bar

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

Since I installed the latest version (2.9) and render with cycles in the viewport, the progress-bar at the top is no longer there. Is it moved/removed or where can I find it?

Best regards
Olle

Comment: There is a x/n in the viewport directly (top left).

Comment: Only finding the top right menu (shortcut N)

Comment: I think you're talking about the render progress bar. When you hit render, just move the pop up window and open the main blender window. In the bottom middle you will find a progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

Open the *Viewport Overlays* popover in the upper right of 3d viewport, to the left of the *Viewport Shading Mode* buttons, the downward arrow next to the two overlapping circles.

Check *Statistics*. If it doesn't appear, try going to a different display mode (*Wireframe* or *Solid*) then back to *Rendered Mode*.

You should then see render progress, as well as the number of objects, vertex, edges, faces and triangles in your seen in the upper left.